# Prevent typescript conversion for identical types

Tags: typescript

In my typescript program I have two coordinate systems, that are convertible to each-other.  They are both x,y but the have different scales.  I would like to setup typescript so that it will warn me if I pass the wrong type to a function.

```js
type Vec2 = [number,number]; // the base type

interface TileC extends Vec2 {};  // the two types I would like to be exclusive
interface ChunkC extends Vec2 {}; // the two types I would like to be exclusive

// example functions

let chunkSize = 32;

function tileToChunk(t: TileC): ChunkC {
  const [x,y] = t;
  const c: Vec2 = [Math.floor(x/chunkSize), Math.floor(y/chunkSize)];
  return c;
}

function chunkToTile(c: ChunkC): TileC {
  const [cx,cy] = c;
  return [cx*chunkSize, cy*chunkSize];
}
```

I would like the following to be an error

```js
let chunkCoord: ChunkC = tileToChunk([7,14]);
let wantError = tileToChunk(chunkCoord);
```

As it stands, this compiles just fine. Am I missing a compiler option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent unintended type compatibility in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661618/how-to-prevent-unintended-type-compatibility-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing, my initial answer actually doesn't work. This version works. Features:

- Allows the base to convert into the extended types
- Does not let extended types convert to each-other
- Does not let extended types convert to base (But can be done with a cast)
- Nicer error messages
- No effect on runtime / generated typescript

code:

```js
// base type
type Vec2 = [number,number];

// lock helpers
interface LockTileC {
  readonly _typelock_tilec?: void;
}

interface LockChunkC {
  readonly _typelock_chunkc?: void;
}

// instanced types
type TileC  = [number,number,LockTileC?];
type ChunkC = [number,number,LockChunkC?];

// This option does it all in one line, but the error messages are worse
// type TileC = [number,number,{readonly _typelock_tilec?: void;}?];
// type ChunkC = [number,number,{readonly _typelock_chunkc?: void;}?];


function baseType(num: Vec2): void {
  console.log(`${num[0]}, ${num[1]}`);
}

function onlyTileC(num: TileC): void {
  console.log(`${num[0]}, ${num[1]}`);
}

function onlyChunkC(num: ChunkC): void {
  console.log(`${num[0]}, ${num[1]}`);
}


function example(): void {
  let asChunk: ChunkC = [1,2];
  let asTile:  TileC  = [32,64];
  let base:    Vec2   = [3,4];

  onlyTileC(asTile);        // OK:    type to type
  onlyTileC(asChunk);       // FAIL:  cross type to cross type
  onlyChunkC(asTile);       // FAIL:  cross type to cross type
  onlyTileC(base);          // OK:    base to type
  onlyChunkC(base);         // OK:    base to type
  baseType(asChunk);        // FAIL:  type to base
  baseType(<Vec2>asChunk);  // OK:    type to base with casting
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing a compiler option, this is by design. TypeScript compiles to JavaScript and hence there is no static type information available at runtime.

TypeScript uses structural typing:

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x.
>
> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Good news is you can use [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) to achieve your desired behavior, for example by adding a `kind` property:

```js
interface TileC {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    kind: "Tile"
}

interface ChunkC {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    kind: "Chunk"
}

interface VecC = TileC | ChunkC
```

Comment: I understand that there is no runtime type information.  I was only hoping for a compile time warning or error.  Your suggestion of kind helps a lot tho, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see my update in the accepted answer.

<strike>After taking a further look into this. I can achieve what I want by doing this.
Note that `_type_lock` can be any name, as long as it's the same name for both (all) similar types.  `"foo"` and `"bar"` can be anything as long as they are unique.  The name of the type is probably a good option here.</strike>

```
type Vec2 = [number,number]; // the base type

interface TileC extends Vec2 {
  _type_lock?: "foo";
};
interface ChunkC extends Vec2 {
  _type_lock?: "bar";
};
```