# restrict generic type <T> to specific types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code snippet, the function `doSomething` should accept only the objects of type Base and not other types that match the type structure something like an `instanceOf` constraint.

```
interface IBase {
    prop1: string;
}

abstract class Base implements IBase {
    constructor() { }
    prop1: string = '';
}
class Derived1 extends Base { }
class Derived2 extends Base { }

class AnotherBase {
    constructor() { }
    prop1: string = '';
}

// T extends Base
function doSomething<T extends Base>(obj: T) {
    // do something
}

//cases should work
doSomething(new Derived1());
doSomething(new Derived2());

// cases should NOT work
doSomething({ prop1: 'test' }); // works
doSomething(new AnotherBase()); // works
```

How can we make the function strictly accept only objects of type Base?
We can understand the present working as per the [type-compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) rules. But, is there an approach to specify a generic constraint to match exact type?

**UPDATE:**

From the answers to this and similar questions, It looks impossible to achieve this compile-time. I decided to include the `instanceOf` check to achieve the expected behaviour at runtime.

```
// T extends Base
function doSomething<T extends Base>(obj: T) {
    if(!( obj instanceof Base)){
        console.log('not a Base type');
        throw new Error('An instance of Base is expected.');
    }
    // do something
}

//cases should work
console.log('Derived1');
doSomething(new Derived1());

console.log('Derived2');
doSomething(new Derived2());

// cases should NOT work
console.log('{..}');
doSomething({ prop1: 'test' }); // doesn't work

console.log('AnotherBase');
doSomething(new AnotherBase()); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Nope.

---

Typescript is structural, not nominal. That makes that if two types has the same interface, *then they are the same type*. That even includes class instances versus object literals.

We can test this with something like:

```
type Exact<A, B> = A extends B ? B extends A ? true : false : false
```

This type alias takes two parameters. If A extends B, and vice versa, then we know typescript considers them to be identical.

```
type IBase_Base = Exact<IBase, Base> // true
type Base_Derived = Exact<Base, Derived> // true
type Derived_ObjLiertal = Exact<Base, { prop1: string }> // true
```

So `class Derived extends Base { }` is identical to `Base` as far as typescript is concerned. in fact a class instance and an object literal are considered identical as long as the instance has the shape as the literal.

---

That said, if the derived class was different in anyway, then you could notice that with the help if this `Exact` type and forbid it.

First you could make a type to enforce that a type exactly match, like:

```
type EnforceExact<Constraint, T> = Exact<Constraint, T> extends true ? T : never
```

Then make your function use this helper:

```
function doSomething<T extends IBase>(obj: EnforceExact<IBase, T>) {
    // do something
}
```

Now if we make the `Derived` class different somehow:

```
class DerivedWithAddition extends Base {
  foo: number = 123
}
```

Then we get a type error when we try to pass this in:

```
doSomething(new DerivedWithAddition()) // not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcUG8CwAUMicgA5QD2ZAjAFzJZhSgDmA3EQL5FEIA22LMkw5kwALZl+ECRHDCM2PEVLIElEEygBXBGEpQAFAEpkuZD2KkK1eo2ZtkAXmQByN50JWBQ5ABFoYAA3CAATZAgAD0gQMOFRPCs+QSxhQJZQsIB1YDAACwBBMLC84E1ImPl4kWVzVWQYSkoGEB0JACNoF2QaACYAZm5eQjAATzIUAFEoxDAAHkKAGhEAPh7Cytia9GQAfhEt6uFNg+YdFAZ4fjEruBuIInHJ5CmQJqgkGbn5gGFNbRwUBgFYAFXWrm++j+AOYQPAYPW0W2wnOKAOoOQrQgoSgIwA9ISnhMUEocAB9RI9KELMkQFaJdaE5Bo4kvRLkjIhcLU2bQxIrLlZJn4lm6R6jEkBIJZckAeQ6ACsADLAaBge68n4C8zkKi0BjaJxcEVii4jIjMzHI461MRGQxmOlEGA6ED6cogZBhSgAZUocgKbHm1qqcUUjIdSoYbw+Xz5tJ14LMBGsJGZPsYAYgQZArGGhBSfkKIEoBWgVNTag0WnO+kMpl1VjUtgNDhYeZ6Hi8yUIPv9gfybCMIAgAHc7RBTCYvP3s7nWCPx9LMuFp7O-fOh3mjBZW-Y3JAmG5LDOiHPB8PRxOS2X8hXlOuLX3N5ed9eV9ycnkiiUypppyIIA)

---

You could also use the *brand* workaround as suggested in [the answer that @kaya3 linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661618/how-to-prevent-unintended-type-compatibility-in-typescript). However, unless there's a very good reason, you probably shouldn't. This structural equivalence is a pretty great feature of typescript. Your life will be easier if you just let someone pass in whatever they want, as long as it has the correct interface.

Comment: Side note: TypeScript has some interesting assignability rules that can cause possibly unexpected behavior in a test like `Exact`.  For example, `Exact<{}, { a?: string }>` is `true`, despite the fact that those are distinct types... so you get fun transitivity failures; `Exact<{b?: string}, {}>` is also `true`, but `Exact<{b?: string}, {a?: string}>` is `false`.  [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/ND534m)

Comment: Good to know! Seems like enforcing structural typing is hard.

Comment: A combination of compile-time and runtime check will help in this case. I've updated the question with the approach that worked for me.